# Load properties file in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a java maven project. i have placed a properties file in `src/main/resources` folder.

```
src/main/resources
  |
  |___properties
        |
        |
        |___custom_en_US.properties
```

I am loading properties file as below in servlet.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("classpath:properties/custom", request.getLocale());
```

but above line is throwing exception saying resource not found. How can i give path to properties file? Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the "classpath" prefix.: `.getBundle("/properties/custom")`

The "classpath" prefix is not a standard, it is defined by some frameworks like spring.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and is working fine. But the problem is i have 20 key value pairs in proeprties file. i want them to be loaded in the same order as they are in properties file. But when i get them in servlet, their order is changed. How can i get the key value pairs in the same order how they are in properties file? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't rely on that, and since the structure is usually a hashtable, you can't have it. If you want them in order, prefix them with something (1_foo, 2_bar), and then order by that.. But normally the order should not matter

Comment: i have to place them in a select box of html. So i need  them in order. Please suggest me if there is anything i can do?

Comment: @user755806 Then you need to write your own code to read and write the properties file. Java Properties won't maintain order.

Answer (score 3):

Read the property file from classpath

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
    prop.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));            
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```