# Why can I load properties in a Java application, but not a Java servlet?

Tags: servlets, fileinputstream, properties-file

(after searching StackExchange) I cannot figure out why I can load my properties file from a simple `Java class` with a `main()` method, but not from a `Java servlet`. The exception is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\dbprops.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)`
Could someone please help me load the properties file into my servlet?
(Assume there are other methods and imports in these classes)

Project layout:

```
project\
    src\
        joerle\
            servlet\
                MyServlet.java
            jdbc\
                JdbcTest.java
    resources\
        dbprops.properties
```

Simple java class `joerle.jdbc.JdbcTest` (loads properties):

```
public class JdbcTest {
    private final String dbPropPath = "resources" + File.separator + "dbprops.properties";
    private Properties props;

    public JdbcTest() {
        try {
            props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(dbPropPath));
            //do stuff
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("properties file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("properties file cannot be opened");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JdbcTest();
    }
}
```

Simple java servlet class `joerle.servlet.MyServlet` (fails to load properties):

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private final String dbPropPath = "resources" + File.separator + "dbprops.properties";
    private Properties props;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(dbPropPath));
            //do stuff
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("properties file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("properties file cannot be opened");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried:
- [Load properties file in servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507981/load-properties-file-in-servlet)
- [Load properties file in Servlet/JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507016/load-properties-file-in-servlet-jsp)
and some other solutions...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used, which works successfully within a servlet context:

- Moved properties file to `projectRoot/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/resources/dbprops.properties`
- and called it with this:
  `InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/dbprop.prope‌​rties");`

Note where the slashes are if you use this solution.
This was a great resource for my trouble-shooting: [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app)